# Why are some of my buttons disabled at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When the window is opened, `Abort` is clickable, but all of the other buttons are not. 
I put breakpoints at my getters:

```
public ICommand OkCommand
        {
            get { return _okCommand; }
        }
```

and the button is disabled after it is called. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Is my binding not setup correctly? Or is it not being correctly initialized?

My ViewModel constructor:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
        public MyViewModel(IMyViewModel view)
            : base(view)
        {
            _okCommand = new DelegateCommand(OkHandler, IsValid);
            _refreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(RefreshHandler, IsValid);
            _testConnCommand = new DelegateCommand(TestConnectionHandler, IsValid);
        }
```

My XAML for two of the buttons.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Content="Ok" IsDefault="True" TabIndex="3" Margin="5,0"/>
            <Button Content="Abort" IsCancel="True" TabIndex="4" Margin="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is your IsValid maybe returning false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the [`DelegateCommand` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654427.aspx) is a `Func` that tells if the `Command` is executable. WPF uses this to determine if buttons, etc should be enabled.

I would check your `IsValid` `Func` / method whether it works okay, that is: returns `true`.